Help in identifying 2 SMD components (JA7? 1B?)
I need help identifying the 2 components in the image. I have already searched for 2 or 3 hours. I believe both are SOT-223 (around 2mm in length).
I forgot how to correctly read the markings.
Equivalents are also ok.


JA is BAV70W from PANJIT, https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/14650/PANJIT/BAV70W.html
1B is BC846BW, https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/857026/HOTTECH/BC846BW.html
